# Is it possible to disable forms authentication for specific subdirectories of an application?

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-7

I have an asp.net application for which I need to expose a particular subdirectory to the public internet. When I go into the subdirectory's IIS configuration's authentication section, I cannot disable the Forms Authentication.

The setting is marked as read-only.

Google offers many discussions when I search for the error message, but I haven't found a clear, working solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use location in root Web.config.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/815174

```
 <location path="Your directory" allowOverride=”false”>
        <system.web>
            <authorization>
                <allow users="*" />
            </authorization>
        </system.web>
    </location>
```

Comment: What would be the configuration if it's route instead of actual folder for "subfolders", this does not work for my case described here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47096577/servicestack-api-documentation-in-swagger-ui-behind-the-closed-doors

Answer (score 3):

In the application's root web.config, open it up and find the "</system.web>" line. Then add something like the code below to enable unrestricted access to a directory:

```
<location path="MY FOLDER/PATH">
    <system.web>
        <authorization> 
            <allow users="*"/>
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
```

Comment: This is under the `<configuration>` tag.