# ServiceStack API documentation in Swagger-UI behind the closed doors

Tags: c#, servicestack, forms-authentication

I want to allow access to swagger-ui and metadata only if user is authenticated (forms auth) on our web app, but I want to allow API access all the time (API have some public methods and some which require basic auth).

So what I did is I added this route prefix for API:

```
public override RouteAttribute[] GetRouteAttributes(Type requestType)
{
    var routes = base.GetRouteAttributes(requestType);
    routes.Each(x => x.Path = "/API" + x.Path);
    return routes;
}
```

And:

```
ServiceRoutes = new Dictionary<Type, string[]> {
{
         typeof(AuthenticateService), new[] { "/api/auth", "/api/auth/{provider}" }
     },
}
```

And this as well in web config:

```
<location path="api">
<system.web>
  <authorization>
    <allow users="*"/>
  </authorization>
</system.web>
```

And the thing is that when I go to `/api/` now that works fine, but when I try invoke some method, I get redirected to my `login` route.

Is there a way to solve this like I started, or there's a better way to protect the documentation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no explicit option to require Authentication on metadata pages but you can use a PreRequestFilter to protect access to the `/metadata` and `/swagger-ui` pages with:

```
PreRequestFilters.Add((req, res) =>
{
    if (req.PathInfo.StartsWith("/metadata") || req.PathInfo.StartsWith("/swagger-ui"))
    {
        var session = req.GetSession();
        if (!session.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            res.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized;
            res.EndRequest();
        }
    }
});
```

And to protect access to the `/openapi` JSON specification if you're using [Swagger 2.0 / Open API Feature](http://docs.servicestack.net/openapi) you can dynamically add the `[Authenticate]` attribute at runtime with:

```
public AppHost()
{
    typeof(OpenApiService)
        .AddAttributes(new AuthenticateAttribute());
}
```

If you're using the older [Swagger 1.2 Plugin](http://docs.servicestack.net/swagger-api) you can protect access to backend Services with:

```
public AppHost()
{
    typeof(SwaggerResource)
        .AddAttributes(new AuthenticateAttribute());
    typeof(SwaggerResources)
        .AddAttributes(new AuthenticateAttribute());
}
```

This assumes you're using [ServiceStack Authentication](http://docs.servicestack.net/authentication-and-authorization) not ASP.NET Auth.

Comment: one more question, I deployed my app on https site so it looks like this: `https://example.com/mywebapp/swagger-ui/` but it keeps redirecting to this: `https://example.com:8443/swagger-ui/` (so adding the port and removing the part where the app actually sits), why is that? When I run it locally it works fine...

Comment: @ShP Because you're going through a Proxy and the generated URL is based on the incoming request. You can set `Config.WebHostUrl` to specify which external URL you want used instead.

Comment: @ShP Maybe you have something else that's doing the redirect, ask a new question including the full HTTP Request/Response Headers.

Comment: Hah, something is wrong when I don't have `/` at the end of `/swagger-ui` in url, when I add `/swagger-ui/` it works fine...

Comment: @ShP because requests to directories without a trailing slash are [automatically redirected to have a trailing slash](http://docs.servicestack.net/releases/v4.5.14#internal-improvements) can disable the redirect with `Config.RedirectDirectoriesToTrailingSlashes=false` but a url without a trailing slash is an invalid request where resources wont be correctly referenced.